# Node.js & mongoose: Is it possible to detect if a user request includes a field that doesn't exist in a schema definition?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

Node.js & mongoose: Is it possible to detect if a user request includes a field that doesn't exist in a schema definition?

If this occurs, I'd like to detect it and take action against the offending IP address as it's likely malicious in nature. Is the above possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [joi validate function](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidatevalue-options), sets the `allowUnknown` flag to false (by default).

In your case, you can utilise this feature to catch the error that is thrown when unknown keys are present. The error that is thrown in this scenario is [object.unknown](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectunknown) (considering your payload is expected to be an object).

---

Example:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const joiSchema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().required()
});

const validationResult = joiSchema.validate({ a: "hello world", b: 2 }, { abortEarly: false });
console.log(validationResult.error.details.some(err => err.type === 'object.unknown')); // true
```

---

Using the last console statement (which outputs to true), you can know if user has sent an invalid value in the payload. You can do something like:

```
if (validationResult.error && validationResult.error.details.some(err => err.type === 'object.unknown')) {
  // block the malicious IP
}
```

Comment: Rvy, this is awesome stuff man! Thanks for sharing ... I've been searching for how to do this for some time and I also happen to use @hapi/join for object validation so this is a simple fix.

Comment: Welcome! Do note that joi is moving out of hapi project. So, you can use joi directly, instead of hapi/joi: https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411.